# SQL Query - Unix timestamp - second newest date

Tags: sql, unix-timestamp

I'm completely new to SQL and just need to create one query to be able to make a function on my blog and I'm taking small steps in the code, but I'm stuck on reciving the second newest unixtime date.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(datum),'%d/%m-%Y') AS newest_postdate_ever,
(SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(datum),'%d/%m-%Y') WHERE datum < (SELECT MAX(datum) FROM table-content)) AS second_newest_postdate_ever


[newest_postdate_ever] => 16/04-2022
[second_newest_postdate_ever] =>
```

But it supposed to say `[second_newest_postdate_ever] => 15/04-2022`

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Comment: If your rdbms supports it you can use `row_number() over (order by datum desc) as rn` in a cte or sub-query and then `where rn = 2`

Comment: I think its MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL version 8 we can use ROW_NUMBER. If it is an earlier version we can do the same thing using a variable. I give you both queries.
Once we have assigned ROW_NUMBER DESC the most recent date has `rn=1` and to get the one before we use `WHERE rn = 2`

```
CREATE TABLE table_content (id int not null auto_increment primary key,datum date not null);
INSERT INTO table_content (datum)VALUES ('2022-01-01'),('2022-02-01'),('2022-03-01')
```

For mySQL 8

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT
  id,
  datum,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (ORDER BY datum DESC) AS rn
 FROM table_content
)
SELECT
  id,
  datum,
  rn
FROM CTE;
```

For any version of mySQL

```
SET @rn = 1;
SELECT
  id,
  datum,
  rn
FROM
(SELECT
  id,
  datum,
  @rn AS rn,
  @rn := @rn + 1
 FROM table_content
 ORDER BY datum DESC
) tc;
```

The same results. rn = 2 is the one we want.

> ```
> id | datum      | rn
> -: | :--------- | -:
>  3 | 2022-03-01 |  1
>  2 | 2022-02-01 |  2
>  1 | 2022-01-01 |  3
> ```

This gives the format you want.

```
SET @rn = 1;
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN rn = 1 
      THEN "newest_postdate_ever"
    WHEN rn = 2 
      THEN "second_newest_postdate_ever"
    END AS "description",
  datum AS "date"
FROM
(SELECT
  id,
  datum,
  @rn AS rn,
  @rn := @rn + 1
 FROM table_content
 ORDER BY datum DESC
) tc
WHERE rn < 3;
```

> ```
> description                 | date      
> :-------------------------- | :---------
> newest_postdate_ever        | 2022-03-01
> second_newest_postdate_ever | 2022-02-01
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73a7459e5d5df391ef4909ba7a9e3282)*

Comment: Hi. I really appreciated you example. I Can't change the database like adding row_number. I'm working in a Wordpress plugin were they allow us to make SQL querys to bring out data and place it in controlled ways in Wordpress. Which limits my in several ways. I'm starting to wonder if I should "shut off" unix timestamp and list normal visual dates. Feels like that would make it easier. But I hoped there was short easy commands for unixtime.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you converting my example to unixtime if it's what's needed elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your code. Will it require to me to add a "rn" column or is "rn" always there?

Comment: rn is generated in the query, it's not a column in the table if that is the question. Go onto DBfiddle and try modifying parameters and adjusting things. The original link will not be broken or spoilt. DBfiddle creates a new reference every time you run it.

Comment: I really like the code, but I can't make it work in my Wordpress Plugin. Could it be because of my server using MariaDB 10.4?

Comment: It works in MariaDB 10.4 : see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=73a7459e5d5df391ef4909ba7a9e3282

Comment: Have you tried both versions?

Comment: I just noticed that I could change database versions in the simulator here and it should work. I have tested both codes. could be that the plugin doesn't allow such commands. I don't know its limits. But RUND, MIN, MAX,SUM and such simpler things works.

I will try some more, and figure out how I "like" your posts. ;)